# Render to texture still rendering to screen in OpenGLES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm trying to get a bunch of stuff done in OpenGLES, but here's where I'm starting - drawing stuff to a texture, then displaying that texture.

I create some buffers:

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &frameBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, frameBuffer);
```

And then I set myself up to draw some lines to a framebuffer.

```
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colours);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2000);
```

I then try to copy this into a freshly made texture.

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nil);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128);
```

And then display the texture.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1};
GLfloat texcoords[] = { 0,1,
                            1,1,
                        0,0,
                        1,0,};

glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoords);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES];
```

What I get is this - my lines displayed at the 'back' of the screen (the way I draw the Triangle Fan means that I can see behind it) which means my lines are being drawn to the renderbuffer, even though I never bind it. On top of that, I get my texture drawn as some weird colours, rather than my lines as I expected.

So I've got two problems here:

**Why are my lines still appearing at the back of the screen if I'm not writing them to a renderbuffer?**

**Am I writing to the texture correctly? If so, why isn't it displaying?**

Comment: You're missing a lot of important code, such as the glFramebuffer* calls (glFramebufferRenderbuffer, etc), but what i don't really understand, is if you bind the framebuffer, it will render to it, not to the screen.

Also, why are you not drawing directly to the texture using the FBO?

Comment: FBO is FramebufferObject, right? Can you elaborate on what that might involve? I've seen mention of this elsewhere but no solid code for it.

With regards to rendering targets, that's exactly my problem too. There's no reason why that should be appearing on the screen, but it is. Still working on it with simpler examples.

Comment: Actually a better question is, what exactly is that you want to do?

Comment: I need to draw some lines, convert them into a texture, and then map that texture onto an object for display on the screen. That's the abstract.

What I /actually/ need to do is draw a bunch of lines on a 2D image, blur that image (using a blur I already have implemented), and display it on the screen. This is the first step towards that - framebuffer to texture (which I would blur, ordinarily) and then texture to screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Framebuffer Object (FBO) to draw directly into a texture, the following tutorials should help you:

http://www.flashbang.se/archives/48

Note that those tutorials are for OpenGL, for OpenGL ES is the same, but the EXT is changed to OES in most methods and enumerations.

Also note that binding a framebuffer (glBindFramebufferEXT/OES) makes all rendering go to that framebuffer (and it's attached textures/renderbuffers), so you need to unbind the framebuffer first before drawing again to the screen, which is made by:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: I've taken a look at that tutorial. It makes a lot of sense, although the code he supplies is not yet working. I'll persevere, thanks for now!